# Debian - Disable console access for specific user

Tags: debian, git, account-restrictions, accounts

I have a server with a `git` server running on it.

I would like git users to be able to clone, push and pull using their linux username and password, but not to be able to login to linux console.

If I lock their account using `passwd -l`, they're not able to login to linux console anymore but it also lock their access to `git`.

If I change their default shell to `/bin/false`, git says `Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.` and putty crashes when I try to login to the server using their credentials.

Any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: Check out [rush](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/rush/) and it's example configuration for [git](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/rush/manual/rush.html#git)

Answer (score 3):

There's a `git-shell` command for this scenario. See [`man git-shell`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell) for details.

Here's how to set it up:

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/git-shell username
```

Assuming there's a `~username/testrepo/.git/`, a git clone will work just fine:

```
git clone username@host:testrepo
Cloning into 'testrepo'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Upon an `ssh username@host`, you'll see

```
fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled.
hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.
```

and the connection will be terminated.

It is possible to create a `~username/git-shell-commands/` directory with scripts in it, but I've not been able to get that to work together with `git clone`, because a script is always run, producing output, corrupting git repository actions. So, it is best to not even create that directory.

---

Here is another way (based on what GitLab does). Make a single `git` user owning all the repositories. It will have all the host keys in `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Each of the lines are prefixed with options, like so.

```
command="~/bin/gitshell.sh",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB34234234.....
```

We can't use `gitlab-shell` here, so we use a custom script `~git/bin/gitshell.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec git-shell -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

This approach doesn't require `chsh` as the command in `authorized_keys` takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you should limit the user on `sshd_config` level, for example :

```
Match User git # or Group git-group
  ForceCommand git-shell
```

from http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-4.html

Comment: or place git-shell in their passwd account. Not pratical in sshd_config if they are several?

Comment: Placing it in the in `passwd` doesn't force the use of this shell if I am right. If there are more uesers, there is nothing easier then use group for all of them.

Comment: I agree with you, if in passwd it can be bypassed easily.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you said and cannot connect anymore through ssh but I cannot clone either : *fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled. hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.*. I created a git-shell-commands for my user, but now when I want to clone it just opens a git command line.

Answer (score -1):

Try `/sbin/nologin` in `/etc/passwd`, user can execute.

Comment: This is the same as `/bin/false` which is mentioned in the question and which does not work.